# Best way to automate SQL scripts by passing variable

Tags: sql, automation, scripting, scheduled-tasks, sql-insert

I have one project in which business provide me some parmateres and based on those parameters I have to do entry in 4 tables using SQL insert statements

Is there any way in which I can create or use some tech/tool which will create SQL scripts and deploy them automatically
 .
So only task should be passing parameters.

Any help and guidance from all the experts would be really great

Thanks in advance

Comment: I dont think there are scripts can be deployed by scent (aromatically).  If you come up with a method please do share.

Answer (score 0):

I generally use Apache Spark with Scala/Python and create SQL dynamically.

An example code/requirement would help.